# grocery crud multiselect field

Tags: multi-select, grocery-crud

No problem to use this function 'multiselect field' which show on this website:

```
http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type

$crud->field_type('fruits','multiselect',
                   array( "1"  => "banana", "2" => "orange", "3" => "apple"));
```

Next step, i try to extract data from database to replace the 'array' in the formulae above but failed, pls advise.

```
$this->db->select('employeeNumber');
$a = $this->db->get('employees')->result();
$crud->field_type('firstName', 'multiselect', $a);
```

I'm getting result like

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [employeeNumber] => 1002 )  
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [employeeNumber] => 1056 )
```

Hmm... how to make it into this format, any advise?:

```
array( "1"  => "banana", "2" => "orange", "3" => "apple")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually do a foreach here. In our case you need to do something like this:

```
$this->db->select('employeeNumber');
$results = $this->db->get('employees')->result();
$employees_multiselect = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $employees_multiselect[$result->employeeNumber] = $result->employeeNumber;
}

$crud->field_type('firstName', 'multiselect', $employees_multiselect);
```

or it is even better if you have the name of the employer to do something like this:

```
$this->db->select('employeeNumber, employeeName');
$results = $this->db->get('employees')->result();
$employees_multiselect = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $employees_multiselect[$result->employeeNumber] = $result->employeeName;
}

$crud->field_type('firstName', 'multiselect', $employees_multiselect);
```

Comment: thank you so much :). One more thing, if i want to add 1 more field like this: select('employeeNumber, employeeName, familyName'); how to output?

Comment: i got it: $employees_multiselect[$result->employeeNumber] = $result->employeeName . $result->familyName;

Comment: Yes this is the correct way to do it. The only missing thing here is the whitespace. So in your case it will be: $employees_multiselect[$result->employeeNumber] = $result->employeeName ." ". $result->familyName; If that helped you then please add one reputation to the answer :-) (this is the up button)

Comment: How do we save the results of multiselect fields? I just get the last id selected in the database.

Comment: You have to do it with callbacks. In your case you have to use callback_insert and callback_update